# What does the M counter in Solo Mode mean?

Tags: mario-party-6

In the Solo Mode of Mario Party 6, there is an M counter located just above the coin count. Initially I thought it might track minigame victories, but the counter didn't increase after winning a minigame.

What does the M counter mean in Solo Mode?

[image: M counter in Mario Party 6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it counts collected minigames on the board, factoring in how many Minigames you've collected over your entire career. So if you win a game you haven't collected, the M counter gets incremented and the game can be stolen by Bowser, and so forth.

Consider the following gameplay footage in which this video plays with most of the games earned prior to starting a new solo game:

Versus this footage where the boards starts with no games earned:

Comment: So in other words, the counter tracks new mini games (marked ???) that you've collected that round.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro That would be my assumption, yes.